# Is there any way we can use the data cached by apollo after a query similar to React's useState? Will there be double store of data if I use useState?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am using a GraphQL as an API for one my NextJS application. I want to manipulate the data queried using filters and other client interacting activities. The only way for me to accomplish that is by using React' `useState()` but I think using it will just be redundant as GraphQL also by default stores the queried data. So, Is there any way I can use cached data of Apollo GraphQL or I am misleading something here. I am new to Apollo Grpahql.

```js
const GET_MOVIES = gql`
    query GetMovies{
        movies{
            id
            name
            genre
            yearReleased
            rating
        }
    }
`

const {data, loading, error, refetch} = useQuery(GET_MOVIES);

const [allMovies, setAllMovies] = useState(data);
```

Comment: Do you want to mutate the data the client side and NOT update it in the server? Or you just want to render the filtered data?

Answer (score 0):

If you know your data is already cached, you can just query the cache using `fetchPolicy: 'cache-only'` - that will *not* hit the network. For me that's the simplest because the API is the same as getting data from the server.

Alternatively you can read/write to the cache yourself directly. [[docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction)]